# jQuery and Angular both in a project

Tags: jquery, angularjs, web-applications

I am new to front end development in web-apps.
I have a very basic/(silly) question.

Like jQuery is a library for javascript functions,
there are other libraries too like Angular.js

I want to know that while working on a project is it 
possible to use both these libraries and harness both of these
libraries functions ?

Comment: Sure, why not? It's considered best practice though to use either of them since they both manipulate the DOM elements.. more reading [here](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/jquery-angularjs-comparison-migration-walkthrough).

Answer (score 2):

> **Does Angular use the jQuery library?**
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being
> bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular
> falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we
> call jQLite.
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer
> might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use both jquery and angular js in one project. Actually AngularjJS has jquery lite build in already, you can extend it by adding the 'full'version of jQuery as well

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use both jquery and angular js in one project

understand basic difference angular js is framework and jquery is library..

---

you can make use of jqlite which is part of angular js instead of including of jquery full  : jQLite is a very stripped version on jQuery. jQLite is enough for angular to work. This is to remove any dependencies. [jqLite In AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2752-using-jquery-instead-of-jqlite-in-angularjs.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Also for Angular to notice changes occuring outside of its scope you want to use $apply()
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Answer (score 0):

Like others said yes you can use jquery in with angular js. And if you are using require js to load your dependencies and modules and use add jquery as dependecy in require.js

Something like this

```
'angular': {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: 'angular'
            }
```